# T-SQL Rearrange the values from 1...n

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to rearrange the rank numbers, currently they are with gaps like 1, 12, 13, 20 that I need to rearrange from 1,2,3,4[image]

after my solution, it is rearranging but I believe there must be lot shorter version to rearrange.

Here is what I have tried:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#rank') is not null drop table #rank
if object_id('tempdb..#rank2') is not null drop table #rank2

select driver_id, zone_name, zone_rank, 0 as updated into #rank from driver_login where zone_name = 'Out of Zone' order by zone_rank 
select * into #rank2 from #rank

select * from #rank2 order by zone_rank

declare @currentRank int
declare @driverId int

while exists(select 1 from #rank2)
begin
    set @currentRank = (select min(zone_rank) from #rank2)
    set @driverId = (select driver_id from #rank2 where zone_rank = @currentRank)

    if(@currentRank != 1 and exists(select 1 from #rank where zone_rank = 1))
    begin
     declare @minRank int = (select max(zone_rank) from #rank where updated = 1)
     update #rank set zone_rank = @minRank + 1, updated = 1 where driver_id = @driverId
    end
    else if(@currentRank != 1 and not exists(select 1 from #rank where zone_rank = 1))
    begin
     update #rank set zone_Rank = 1, updated = 1 where driver_id = @driverId
    end


    delete from #rank2 where driver_id = @driverId
end

select * from #rank order by zone_rank
```

Here is the output of my code:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SQL Server 2008 you can use [ranking functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and one of the following statements:

```
-- Table
CREATE TABLE driver_login (
   driver_id int, 
   zone_name varchar(20), 
   zone_rank int
)
INSERT INTO driver_login
   (driver_id, zone_name, zone_rank)
VALUES
   (100, 'Out of Zone', 5),
   (113, 'Out of Zone', 10),
   (101, 'Out of Zone', 12),
   (114, 'Out of Zone', 13)

-- SELECT statement
SELECT 
   driver_id, 
   zone_name, 
   RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY zone_name ORDER BY zone_rank) zone_rank, 
   1 as updated 
INTO #rank 
FROM driver_login
WHERE zone_name = 'Out of Zone' 

SELECT *
FROM #rank

-- UPDATE statement
;WITH UpdateCTE AS (
   SELECT 
      driver_id, 
      zone_name,
      zone_rank,
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY zone_name ORDER BY zone_rank) AS RankID
   FROM driver_login
   WHERE zone_name = 'Out of Zone' 
) 
UPDATE UpdateCTE
SET zone_rank = RankID

SELECT *
FROM driver_login
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

> Returns the rank of each row within the partition of a result set. The
>   rank of a row is one plus the number of ranks that come before the row
>   in question.
>
> ROW_NUMBER and RANK are similar. ROW_NUMBER numbers all rows
>   sequentially (for example 1, 2, 3, 4, 5). RANK provides the same
>   numeric value for ties (for example 1, 2, 2, 4, 5).

You will have something like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT driver_id,
        RANK() OVER(ORDER BY driver_id) AS RN
    FROM #rank
)
UPDATE #rank
SET zone_rank = RN
FROM #rank INNER JOIN
    CTE ON YourTable.driver_id = CTE.driver_id
```

Comment: `order by driver_id` will give wrong result. You should order by the existing `zone_rank`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select dl.*,
             row_number() over (order by zone_rank) as new_zone_rank
      from driver_login dl
     )
    set zone_rank = new_zone_rank,
        updated = 1
    where zone_rank <> new_zone_rank;
```